# warning: relocation against `c_func' in read-only section `.text'

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, compiler-errors, nasm

I am trying to link a C object file and a NASM object file. The C file is supossed to call an assembly function, and that assembly function is supposed to call another C function. Here is some pseudo-code of the 2 files:

```c
void asm_func(int a);
void c_func(int a, int b);

void c_func(int a, int b) {
    /* ... */
}

int main() {
    asm_func(5);
    return 0;
}
```

```
section .text
    extern c_func
    global asm_func

asm_func:
    ; ...

    call c_func

    ; ...
```

Although, I also tried doing:

```
section .data
    extern c_func
    global asm_func

section .text
    ; ...
```

I am compiling and linking with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -m32 -fPIC -c -o obj/c_file.c.o src/c_file.c
nasm -f elf32 -o obj/asm_file.asm.o src/asm_file.asm
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast -m32 -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so obj/c_file.c.o obj/asm_file.asm.o -lm
```

The warnings are:

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/asm_file.asm.o: warning: relocation against `c_func' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a shared object
```

Note that all of this is compiled and linked into a 32 bit shared object.

Comment: Instead of calling `call c_func`, would this work instead `mov eax, [c_func]` 
`call eax` to remove that linker warning?

Comment: No, exact same warning. I also tried adding `default rel` on top of the file since I am compiling and linking with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Works fine here. Make sure what you posted is actually enough to reproduce the issue. A relative `call` should not need a relocation.

Comment: @Jester did you compile with the same parameters as me? Keep in mind, I am compiling a 32 bit shared object library.

Comment: Yes, I used your commands. Edit: actually on closer inspection I do get a relocation it's just that my version of `ld` does not complain about it.

Comment: Well, I just pasted the exact example I used here with the exact same commands (only adding a `printf()` inside `c_func()` and including `stdio.h`) and I get the same warnings. I am using `gcc 13.2.1 20230801` and `NASM version 2.16.01 compiled on Mar 18 2023`.

Comment: Anyway, as a quick fix try to go through the PLT using `call c_func wrt ..plt` Alternatively pass `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` option for linking.

Comment: I actually saw the `wrt ..plt` thing in the NASM documentation and I think I tried it (I am not sure since I tried so many things), but I removed it because I didn't know what it was doing.

Comment: `default rel` does nothing in 32-bit mode (`-m32`); x86-64 only has RIP-relative addressing in 64-bit mode.  `mov eax, [c_func]` would be a load from that absolute address (4 bytes of machine code).  `mov eax, c_func` / `call eax` would use the absolute address as an immediate and then jump to it instead of making a relative `call`, so @vengy's suggestion is the opposite of what you want, and would definitely require DT_TEXTREL in position-independent code. Maybe they were picturing that `c_func` would be a global variable holding a pointer, but a `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode won't work

Comment: Are you sure it's the `call c_func` instruction that's the problem?  `call rel32` should be resolved to a relative address with no fixup needed.  Are you maybe using `c_func` another way in your asm?  Or no, I just tried it myself; weird.  Oh, right, because we're making a shared library and `c_func` has non-hidden visibility, so symbol interposition is a thing.  So there's a relocation entry on the call target in case the symbol is found in another shared object first (like `LD_PRELOAD`) for symbol interposition.

Comment: Yup, adding `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` to `c_func` in the `.c` source removes the linker warning.  IIRC there's a GCC option to make "hidden" the default for symbols, so you have to explicitly mark symbols as global to export them from your shared lib.

Comment: Otherwise yes, calling through the PLT is another way of making position-independent code, if you do want to export `c_func` outside the shared lib, and you can't or don't want the hack of defining an alias for it with hidden visibility, if that's possible.  (I forget how, like maybe a GNU C `__attribute__((alias("name")))` or weakalias on a prototype to declare it as another name for a function, or maybe possible in asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had some trouble understanding 90% of what you said but thank you for taking the time of checking all this out.

Comment: Well, hopefully you have some keywords to search on to read more about this, especially **symbol interposition** as the reason why `ld -shared` doesn't want to resolve `call c_func` to a `call rel32` directly to the address of the C function in the other object file.  (`call rel32` is position independent since it uses a relative offset, not an absolute address, so works without a TEXTREL in a shared library.)

Comment: So did you try `call c_func wrt ..plt`, `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` or `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`? Any of those work for you? Do you still have a problem?

Comment: I ended up using `wrt ..plt`, thank you for your help.

Comment: PLT is the least efficient way; calls within your shared library go through an extra `jmp` (in the PLT).  But if you only care about it working, not efficiency, then sure.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's good to know, since performance is important here. Thank you.